# Android Image Looping

Tags: java, android, image, loops, animation

I wanted to loop three images switching like this. 
http://www.transum.org/software/SW/SnailRace/DiceAnimated.gif

```
int i=1;
    while(i<5000){
    enemyj.setImageResource(R.drawable.paper);
    i++;
    enemyj.setImageResource(R.drawable.rock);
    i++;
    enemyj.setImageResource(R.drawable.sciss);
    i++;

}
```

the duration is there but there is no image showing. the image afterwards is showing fine

Comment: this loop code makes really no sense

Comment: what about TweenAnimation...? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html

Comment: Cant you just create a gif and use that?

Comment: You need to re-think your code before ask this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is [AnimationDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html) take a look at official page, or check it on google

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `AnimationDrawable`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a blocking while loop - only the last setImageResource will be visible to the user.

I suggest you check out Frame Animations: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Frame